# Объясните без хейта, что происходит в куске кода

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

объясните суть данного метода и что в нем происходит

Comment: Изините, но показать программисту картинку и сказать, что на ней есть код, это более чем хейт.

Comment: @0xdb так, а что ещё должен скинуть когда переменные, и поля не используются в других методах, я хочу понять, что в этом методе происходит

Comment: Код как **текст**. А заодно пояснить, что в коде непонятно, и почему документация не помогла это выяснить.

Comment: @0xdb в доке, написано, от какие классов наследуется класс, и синтаксис и всё. там толком не написано в какие случаях применять данный класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод принимает сообщение из сокета.

```
var msg = s as SocketUserMessage; // проверка что сообщение не системное. 
//Если сообщение не от пользователя метод ничего не делает
var context // создаёт контекст на основе сообщения
//Если пользователь бот метод ничего не делает
//Проверка на мут(пользователь не может писать сообщения/говорить)
var userAccount // получение аккаунта пользователя от которого сообщение
userAccount.IsMuted // показывает может ли пользователь с этим аккаунтом отправлять сообщения


Message.DeleteAsync// если аккаунт замьючен удаляет сообщение
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное! Вы разбираетесь в дискорд ботах?